# Wireshark Boolean custom field/column

Tags: wireshark

I'd like to have a custom column in Wireshark that shows whether the traffic is incoming or outgoing.

I was hoping I could enter a boolean in the fields column like this:

[image: Column Preferences]

This gives an error though.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

I know I can use colorization to indicate incoming and outgoing but it's more hassle.

Comment: You can only add fields, not field expressions, so what you're attempting to do won't work.  There are some possible solutions though, but what field are you trying to use to determine direction?  The screenshot shows "ip.src == 127.0.0.1", but that's the loopback address and will also be the destination address too, won't it?  I don't think that'll help you determine direction.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard I'd replace the `127.0.0.1` with the actual local IP address and use the destination address.

Answer (score 1):

*I know I can use colorization to indicate incoming and outgoing but it's more hassle.*

I don't know if what I'm about to propose is any less of a hassle to you, but you could try the following as an alternative:

Let's assume your local IP address is 192.168.1.100 and the remote host's IP address is 192.168.1.200.  Edit your `hosts` file to include an entry for each one, so:

```
192.168.1.100    OUTBOUND  
192.168.1.200    INBOUND
```

*The `hosts` file can be found in your Wireshark Personal configuration directory, which you can look up using "Wireshark: Help -> About Wireshark -> Folders".  Note that if you are working with a particular profile, you should edit the corresponding `hosts` file within that profile directory instead.*

Now add a new "Direction" column in Wireshark and select "Net src addr (resolved)" as the Type.  Check that you have the "Resolve network(IP) addresses" preference enabled  under the "Name Resolution" section.  You don't need to use an external resolver, so you can check "Only use the profile hosts file" option if you like.

After you restart Wireshark, the column will indicate `INBOUND` or `OUTBOUND` for those matching IP addresses.  All other IP addresses will not be resolved, but you will see their IP address in that column as well.  Of course, if your capture file only contains traffic to/from those 2 IP addresses, then you'll only see the direction indicator in the column.

Now, since you added those IP addresses to the "hosts" file, the default *Source* and *Destination* columns will also display `INBOUND` or `OUTBOUND`, as the case may be, which could be potentially confusing, so you can either hide those columns or remove them entirely and replace them with "Net src addr (unresolved)" and "Net dest addr (unresolved)".  You may want to create a separate user profile to customize these columns for this particular use case, and leave the default profile settings alone.

Comment: That is more hassle, however I'm gonna given you an up vote because that's a cracking, out-of-the-box, convoluted hack.  Hats off to you sir.  `(◔‿◔)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that is hopefully less of a hassle.  Use a Lua post-dissector to grab the source and destination IP addresses and then create a new IP Post-dissector direction field based on the IP pairs.  For example:

```
local ippost = Proto("IPpost", "Set direction based on IP pairs")

-- Fields
local ippost_dir_f = ProtoField.string("ippost.direction")
ippost.fields = { ippost_dir_f }

-- Preferences
ippost.prefs.outbound_ip = Pref.string("Outbound IP Address", "1.2.3.4")
ippost.prefs.inbound_ip = Pref.string("Inbound IP Address", "5.6.7.8")

function ippost.dissector(tvb, pinfo, tree)
    local addr_src = pinfo.net_src
    local addr_dst = pinfo.net_dst

    if addr_src and addr_dst then
        if (tostring(addr_src) == ippost.prefs.outbound_ip) and
            (tostring(addr_dst) == ippost.prefs.inbound_ip) then
            tree:add(ippost_dir_f, "OUTBOUND"):set_generated()
        elseif (tostring(addr_src) == ippost.prefs.inbound_ip) and
            (tostring(addr_dst) == ippost.prefs.outbound_ip) then
            tree:add(ippost_dir_f, "INBOUND"):set_generated()
        else
            tree:add(ippost_dir_f, ""):set_generated()
        end
    end
end

register_postdissector(ippost)
```

Adjust the IP pairs in the post-dissector preferences or directly edit them in the lua script.  Save this Lua script as something like `ippost.lua` and place it in your *"Personal Lua Plugins"* directory, which you can find listed in Wireshark's *Help -> About Wireshark -> Folders*.

Once you've saved the script there, restart Wireshark (if it's already running) and then right-click on the "`ippost.direction`" information in the packet details pane and choose, *"Apply as Column"*.  Drag & drop the column to whatever location you prefer, and tweak the Lua script as you see fit.

Refer to the [Wireshark Lua wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua) for more information on Lua and Lua postdissectors.